# Why doesn't my first selector work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a Jquery selector question I have not been able to figure out.

Given a select box in the document like

```
<select id="N7_e7a18384-dfd4-4d6e-aaf2-7e221fde1fb3__WeightTypeID" 
name="N7[e7a18384-dfd4-4d6e-aaf2-7e221fde1fb3].WeightTypeID" disabled="">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Actual</option>
<option value="2">Estimated</option>
<option value="3">Gross</option>
</select>
```

When I try to use a selector like

```
 $("select[id^='WeightTypeID']").prop("disabled", false);
```

it doesn't seem to select and disable the drop down list.

However,

```
 $("form").find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
```

works just fine.  Can someone explain why that first selector does not pick up the drop down list?  I would like to understand so I don't waste time on it again.  I am really puzzled.

Comment: this selector mean id^='WeightTypeID', id starts with "WeightTypeID"

Comment: `^=` means begins with

Comment: My search-fu is weak, I cannot find the dupetarget I *know* must exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `name^=value` is the [attribute **begins** with](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) selector. For just "contains" you'd use `*=`. For "ends with," `$=`.